# Chrome gap below iframe inside absolute div with border

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe, chromium

The gap below the iframe is always twice the border width. This problem does not occur in Firefox or IE.

[image: Chrome screenshot]

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KLH5w/

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

    /* Make box sizes include the border, which is more convenient in most cases */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
}

iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    border-style: dashed;
}

#frame_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="frame_container">
        <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

It can be solved easily enough by placing the iframe in a 100% width/height div.

I'm guessing it's a bug, but does anybody have an explanation, or an elegant CSS solution?

---

Edit1: `box-sizing` appears to be part of the problem. Here is a screenshot without it:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Unfortunately that (expectedly) messes up the border positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure why Chrome behaves awkwardly... But if anyone's interested in workaround, than you can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KLH5w/4/)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

    /* Make box sizes include the border, which is more convenient in most cases */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}

iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    border-style: dashed;
}

#frame_container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Comment: Setting a height misses the point. Removing `box-sizing` alone makes the iframe border overlap the div border.

Comment: @Zantier Is [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236043) relevant?

Comment: Your new answer using `calc()` is good! It also works in IE8 if you replace `height: 100%` with `bottom: 0px` in `#frame_container`.

Comment: I've opened it in IE8. It works fine and falls back to using the `bottom:0px` if you make the change I suggested.

Comment: @Zantier I am not sure whether it works, but you have commented so I won't edit, as I would like to keep my answer as a standard :) so if it works for you and it suffices your needs than you can surely stick to it..